# How to read my words.txt into a array?

Tags: java, arrays, file

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Hangman {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
        // importing file for wordbank
    //  File wordbank = new File("words.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( new File ("words.txt"));

        String [] wordBank = new String [20];

        while ( scan.hasNext() ){
            for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                wordBank[x] = line;
            }

        }
        System.out.println( wordBank[1]);

    }
}
```

my error are below. Im not sure what this means.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: words.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Hangman.main(Hangman.java:8)
```

Comment: What do you think this means: _The system cannot find the file specified._?

Comment: Place the file where Java can find them :-)

Comment: Where is the file you want to read? How is its position related to place from where you run this application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file called words.txt (containing your json data) in the same directory as the java file you are running. Also uncomment the line that says

`File wordbank = new File("words.txt");`